# How to pull a section of a JSON array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, vimeo, custom-fields

Hey guys I really need some help here.

My JSON feed gives me this as a key/value pair:

`"custom_fields":{"zn_meta_elements":["a:8:{s:7:\"sp_link\";a:2:{s:3:\"url\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"target\";s:6:\"_blank\";}s:6:\"sp_col\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"sp_show_social\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"port_media\";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:\"dynamic_element_type\";s:10:\"port_media\";s:21:\"port_media_image_comb\";a:3:{s:5:\"image\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";}s:21:\"port_media_video_comb\";s:26:\"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/112591203\";}}s:15:\"page_title_show\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"page_title\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"page_subtitle\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"zn_disable_subheader\";s:2:\"no\";}"]}`

The variable I want to get a value from is the `port_media_video_comb`
So I want to pull the `http:\/\/vimeo.com\/112591203\` part and turn it into a usable url.

The code I'm currently using to pull info looks like this:

```
jQuery.each(data.posts, function(i, item) {
   html += '<li>';
   html += '<div class="entry"><img src="' + data.posts[i].thumbnail + '" width="50px" height="50px" style="float:left; padding-right: 5px;"><a href="' + data.posts[i].url +'" target="_blank">' + data.posts[i].title + '</a><br /><p>' + data.posts[i].date + '</div>' ;
   html += '</li>';
});
```

Would I do like, `data.posts[i].custom_fields.port_media_video_comb` but then how to I make sure it works as a url? I'm going to use it in a `<iframe>` tag.

Any help is appreciated!

---

EDIT:

Okay so I used this site: http://json.parser.online.fr/
To help me figure out kind of the element I need to grab.

I found that I could get to the string like this:
`data.posts[i].custom_fields.zn_meta_elements` and that returns:
`"a:8:{s:7:\"sp_link\";a:2:{s:3:\"url\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"target\";s:6:\"_blank\";}s:6:\"sp_col\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"sp_show_social\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"port_media\";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:\"dynamic_element_type\";s:10:\"port_media\";s:21:\"port_media_image_comb\";a:3:{s:5:\"image\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";}s:21:\"port_media_video_comb\";s:26:\"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/112591203\";}}s:15:\"page_title_show\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"page_title\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"page_subtitle\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"zn_disable_subheader\";s:2:\"no\";}"`
As a string.

How can I grab just the http://... part to the semi-colon and turn that into a url-friendly.. url?

Comment: This is not JSON.  It is a different form of serialization (PHP perhaps?). You need to find appropriate deserializer and deserialize into a data structure you can read the data you want from.

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize this string so that you can simply access the properties you need: custom_fields = JSON.parse(custom_fields); That's the whole point of JSON: no need to deal with strings, this is an object!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is just to get a url from a very long string so you can use regular expression to achieve this. Here is the code:

```
var s = "a:8:{s:7:\"sp_link\";a:2:{s:3:\"url\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"target\";s:6:\"_blank\";}s:6:\"sp_col\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"sp_show_social\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"port_media\";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:\"dynamic_element_type\";s:10:\"port_media\";s:21:\"port_media_image_comb\";a:3:{s:5:\"image\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";}s:21:\"port_media_video_comb\";s:26:\"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/112591203\";}}s:15:\"page_title_show\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"page_title\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"page_subtitle\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"zn_disable_subheader\";s:2:\"no\";}";
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var url = s.match(regex)[0]; //"http://vimeo.com/112591203"
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/eotbu0sw/2/)

You may reference this stackoverflow article about what regular expression to use to find a url.
[What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: The OP should focus on deserialization not regex manipulation.

Comment: Mike,

"a:8:{s:7:\"sp_link\";a:2:{s:3:\"url\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"target\";s:6:\"_blank\";}s:6:\"sp_col\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"sp_show_social\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"port_media\";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:20:\"dynamic_element_type\";s:10:\"port_media\";s:21:\"port_media_image_comb\";a:3:{s:5:\"image\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";}s:21:\"port_media_video_comb\";s:26:\"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/112591203\";}}s:15:\"page_title_show\";s:3:\"yes\";s:10:\"page_title\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"page_subtitle\";s:0:\"\";s:20:\"zn_disable_subheader\";s:2:\"no\";}" is not a json string so how can you deserialize it?

Comment: It appears to be a PHP serialization, so one would need to deserialize it using PHP, deserialize using a javascript implementation of PHP desrialization such as http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/, or fix the API itself to actually return JSON (if this is under his control).

Comment: I'm using a JSON API plugin for wordpress that returns this information. I'll look into deserialization. Never dealt with this before so thank you :)

Also the regexp stuff is so confusing to me but the code above seems to work thus far, so thank you!